# Does a VSR current rating affect the size of leisure batteries that it can charge?

Tags: relay, current-rating

(Apologies if this is a silly question, I don't do much electronics.)

I'm converting a van into a camper. I've bought three 12V 95Ah AGM batteries (which, incidentally, will be hooked up to a solar panel) that I want to be charged by the engine when I'm driving. I'll be hooking them up in parallel, meaning that essentially I'll have a 285Ah leisure battery.

It seems that the split-charging system I want is a VSR (Voltage-Sensitive Relay) between the starter battery and the leisure batteries. When looking into buying them, I see that they have different current ratings.

What is this rating relative to? Lower-rated ones are, of course, cheaper, but I don't want to sacrifice safety by shaving off some cost. Would a 140A VSR be okay? Do I need a 300A one?

(If I haven't provided enough information for an answer, feel free to ask for more details via a comment and I'll include them.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Current rating of the PVR must exceed the Short circuit current of the PV in full sun by some margin. e.g. >  pref 30%. So if it is a 20Amp panel Ishort circuit then no problem.

### the bigger problem

When the batteries are at different levels then the current connecting them together depends on battery resistance which depends on battery specs. e.g. if 1V difference and ESR is 5V/700CCA=7 milliohms then the switches must conduct 1V /7 mohms = 140 Amps.  (even if only for a short time)

I used CCA test specs of a 5V drop at CCA level and I guestimated your CCA rating.

It is basically a MOSFET pair (for each battery) with a regulator and comparator to act as a smart switch with reverse protection for the PV.

When the engine is started and the start
battery reaches 13.7 volts, the VSR engages, allowing two battery
banks (start and house) to be charged simultaneously. When the
voltage drops below 12.8 volts (eg the engine is stopped), the VSR
disengages, separating the batteries.

So VSR rating depends mainly on battery capacity ESR and voltage difference when turning on PV above threshold.  There are tricks to get around this with a bypass relay and circuit but I wont get into that here.  ( Like a head lamp current limiter and bypass switch._)

Comment: Re: what you say about the PV/PVR, I'm assuming you're talking about the solar panel? If so, surely charging via the panel is separate to charging via the engine? I mean, obviously they'd both be connecting to the leisure batteries but even so it shouldn't affect the VSR, right? (Also, on this point, do I need a setup whereby the batteries aren't getting charged by the panel when the engine's on? Or is it okay to have them both charging them simultaneously?)

Comment: yes OK to charge both simulataneously. When engine is not running and leisure battery is dead, the risk is the load on the generator and VSR when connecting them in parallel to the generator.  Not sure what the current limit is on generator, or other details around the switch circuit, but basically the bigger the batteries, the bigger the VSR current rating due to lower ESR. (effective Series R of battery related to CCA) although when totally dead, ESR rises so current starts slow then increases when connected to engine start.

Comment: Cheers. So, would you say that for safety I should go for e.g. a 300A rated VSR? Or is that overkill? I can get you the specs for the batteries if you need them

Comment: The actual physics of where the current goes between alternator and dual battery switched on after engine start depends on stat of charge, alternator current limit, wire resistance, cell age, Usually the 1st that blows on a car alternator is one of the 6 rectifier diodes after a car start with a really solid connection to a dead battery and a 160A alternator

Comment: These may actually use like  solenoids with a lower power hold mode so they don't get hot instead of MOSFETs so will chatter and arc and the contacts only if the generator is too weak which would cause cut-out then energize cycles clicking until stable which can wear out contacts faster.   Since I am making a lot of assumptions, your marine maintenance dept. will know what fails and what is best.  If it is just a starter solenoid, designed to take  e.g. 10A to activate then reduced to 1A to hold it could be relatively cheap and marked up relative huge.

Comment: But I think Marine VSR's are motorized heavy duty transfer switches.  ( priced for those can afford big boats) but could be made relatively inexpensively by a reputable Japanese company.

Comment: How about 275A http://www.aquafax.co.uk/product/8-90051-bep-701-mdvs-24v-dual-volt-sens-battery-switch-24v-275a